# When we allow usesCleartextTraffic property in android, auto refresh is not working in react native. What is the solution for that?

Tags: android, react-native

After android version 9 Pie, we need to use **usesCleartextTraffic** property for network security purposes, but when I am using this property with react native **auto-refresh** is not happening.

```
<application 
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" 
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" 
    .
    . 
>
    --
    --
    --
</application>
```